# Run callback on removeBlock action

Tags: block-editor

I want to run a function when a block is removed. I found this action that seems appropriate https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-block-editor/#removeblock

I added the following to the main block script and the code is definitely executed, because if I remove the namespace, I get an error.

```
wp.hooks.addAction('removeBlock', 'foo', function(arg){
  console.log('gfgdfg');
});
```

However when I remove a block, notthing is logged in the console.
Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: or are these redux store actions?

Comment: Yes @Paul, they are, and `removeBlock()` is a function for removing a block. It doesn't fire an action hook named `removeBlock`, but you can use [`wp.data.subscribe()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#subscribe) to listen to changes in specific part of a store.

Comment: I'd be interested in concrete examples of using subscribe. I found this github issue which has a suggestion https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/41679 - I'm surprised there's no straightforward way like the PHP `post-delete` hook.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but wanted to add my answer to help the future readers. I had the same need and after some digging I found out that this can be achieved with `useEffect()` hook.

Just return an anonymous function from `useEffect()` callback and it will be executed when the block is removed (unmounted). Passing an empty array as the 2nd parameter to `useEffect()` makes the callback run when the block is added or removed.

```
(() => {
    const {registerBlockType} = wp.blocks;
    const {createElement, useEffect} = wp.element;
    const {useBlockProps} = wp.blockEditor;

    function edit(props) {
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('Block added');
        
            return () => {
                console.log('Block deleted');
            }
        }, []);

        return createElement('div', useBlockProps(), 'My block');
    }

    function save(props) {
        return createElement('div', useBlockProps(), 'My block');
    }

    registerBlockType('my-blocks/my-block', {
        edit: edit,
        save: save,
    });
})();
```

This is behaviour described in the [React useEffect() documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#connecting-to-an-external-system).